# Health App on iPhone 6 recognizes there is data, but doesn't display data

Tags: ios, health.app

I use the Sleep Cycle app to track how much I sleep over time, and I've recently wanted to do some analysis on how much I sleep.

On the Apple-provided Health app, while the app shows there is information from today, April 4 all the way back to December 30 (when I first started using the app), on the "All Recorded Data" section of the Sleep category, the area that shows a breakdown of how much you've slept (the purple rectangle that should show a graph) says there is "No Data"

Is this an issue with my phone? I know that Sleep Cycle is allowed to write data on Sleep Analysis, but for some reason it's not working... Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you tap on 'All recorded data' in the Health app, what does it show?

Comment: Here's an imgur album I just created to show how my app looks when I click on all the relevant tabs: http://imgur.com/a/Hpgnl

Comment: Your screens hots look OK to me.   use Sleep Time instead of Sleep Cycle. I've had many problems with Sleep Cycle so I stopped using it. Maybe you can uninstall the app and try something new, see if that helps.